# SQL Server 2008, Error: 948 While Attach Database got Version error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Yesterday I installed SQL Server 2008 on my laptop (Windows 7 64 bit), I need to attach a `.mdf` to the server, but when I try to do this, I get this error:

> Attach Database failed for server 'prince/sqlexpress' (Microsoft.SqlServer.smo)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   1.An Exception Occured while executing a Transact Sql statement or Batch (Microsoft.SqlServer.connectioninfo)
>
> 2.Unable to open the Physical file Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)

With the help of Internet, I found some solution.

> 1.Start SQL Server manager as Administrator (right-click on the program, choose "Start as administrator"):

But I still got the same error.

That `.mdf` file does have have permission, so I moved into external drive (pendrive because my system have only `C:\` drive, yet no partition I have done ) .

Then I got another error,

> Attach database failed for Server 'Prince\SQLEXPRESS'.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The database 'Databasename' cannot be opened because it is version
>   655. This server supports version 611 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported. Could not open new database 'Databasename'. CREATE
>   DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)

I use the Query -

> "select @@version;"

I got the Output as

> "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (Intel X86) Feb 9 2007
>   22:47:07 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition
>   on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7600: )"

what shall i do? But i installed SQL Server 2008. how do i change that?
How to solve this error, please help out this problem, If you have any solution please post it.

Comment: Which sql version you have ??It seems to that the database which you are attaching was written on a higher version compare to the one which you have .Ex- You cannot attach 2008R2 database(mdf) onto a 2008 sql server

Comment: Ok..using Sql server 2008 version 10 , I dont know which version that mdf file.. how to find that one.

Comment: The error points out that ur actually using sql server 2005 because of the version 611 .I'm not sure but can you post the version by executing the statement select @@version

Comment: ok i will check and post after 3 hours

Comment: Did you install SQL Server 2008 **EXPRESS** or a standard/enterprise edition? The error indicates that the `.\SQLEXPRESS` instance you have is SQL Server **2005** Express - maybe you just need to attach the `.mdf` to the 2008 instance (which has a different name - or no name at all, being the default instance)

Comment: how to check SQL Server 2008 EXPRESS or a standard/enterprise edition?

Comment: What did your setup tell you when you ran it? The setup app will show what version and edition it is. Also: what **instance name** did you choose when setting up SQL Server 2008? That's one of the things you need to decide on - what did you decide to use?

Comment: Praveen-I use ur Query -"select @@version;" I got the Output as "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (Intel X86) Feb 9 2007 22:47:07 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7600: )" what shall i do? But i installed SQL Server 2008. how do i change that?

Comment: Since your are running SQL server 2005 and want to attach a databaase which was created using sql server 2008 or 2008R2 .there is no way you can do that .

Comment: No, Again reinstall sql2008.. but still shows 2005 why this.. how to change the instance

Comment: Same problem when the MDF was on a different drive (not on C:). Resolved by running Management Studio as administrator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is very clear: the database MDF file is version **655**. Your server understands version **611**. Which means, despite to your claim to the contrary, that you are connected to a SQL Server 2005. Install a SQL Server 2008, connect to it, and attach your database. Please pay attention during the installation process to the instance name you choose and make sure you connect to that instance. You can also check now what instances you have installed, look at what services you have on your system. `MSSQLSERVER` will be the default instance, `MSSQL$<instancename>` will be a named instance. Use any SCM query tool to see what services you have installed, eg. [`sc.exe`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Already i have installed VS2008 and then i start to install SQL server 2008 , it does not install it shows some problem due to VS2008. So for i uninstall VS2008 and then install SQL server 2008 and then install VS2008. After that i attached .mdf file it shows above mentioned Error.

Comment: No you didn't. I trust the error message more than I trust you.

Comment: oh that's fine , as per reviews all are mentioned to check the Version. how to check server instance name?

Comment: [`SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName');`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx)

Comment: I use this Query -"select @@version;"  I got the Output as "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (Intel X86)   Feb  9 2007 22:47:07   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7600: )"  what shall i do?

Comment: Remus Rusanu- I use ur query-"select serverproperty('Instancename');" get output as- SQLEXPRESS

Comment: So you have SQL Server 2005 instance named 'SQLEXPRESS', and you are connected to it. This is the instance installed by Visual Studio 2008. You must either upgrade this instance to SQL Server 2008, or install a separate one. Start the SQL Server Express 2008 installation and pay attention to the various options and choices presented. Read the dialogs and messages on screen before dismissing them. Don't press Next or OK until you've read and understand everything it says.

Comment: i uninstall sql and vs2008 then some components are still uninstall, what shall i do

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio needs Administrator rights to attach database in Windows 7. If you execute it directly so you will get the error 5120. Fix this executing Management Studio icon using the right mouse button and selecting execute as administrator. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I Solved My Problem,

Stop the SQLEXPRESS service and Uninstall all the Components related to SQL server 2005.
Then Open the registry Editor Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE--SOFTWARE--MICROSOFT--MICROSOFT SQL SERVER-DELETE the folder 90. Then again reinstall SQL Server 2008 and create new instanse for 2008 server. Now its working, I m able to Attach the mdf file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting **`Error:948`** in SQL Server while attaching the databases, try the below steps once:-

- Search **services** in window search bar, Open "Services", search with SQL Server, you will get multiple services. *//Just Keep an eye, nothing needs to do now on this step*.
- Open windows **Control Panel** and uninstall SQL SERVER and **all of the things related to SQL Server** *// Make sure nothing is remain in your system related to SQL SERVER*
- Once you are done with uninstall, search *Services* in search bar and find if you have any services left related to SQL Sever.
- If all of the SQL services are disappeared, you are good to re-install the SQL Server again.

**`With these steps, i am able to handle this error and able to attach the databases. Please read it carefully and after reading this; if think these steps will help, tried it`**.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).